# Generate numbers in range -- SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, random, numbers

I have to generate random values in a range with case statements.

For example, we have a table of products as follows:

*Product*
TV
Refrigerator
Laptop

Now I need to generate COSTPRICE, SALEPRICE for testing purpose. Since the price of the products varies from one to another, I need to generate values in a range.
 For example, 
if the value is TV, then generate values between 1000 to 1100 
OR
 if the value is Refrigerator, then generate values between 800-1000
and so on.

Any ideas/functions how I could approach this using SQL?
I am aware of the function RAND(), but I cannot generate range values with this.

Please help me at least to push myself to find a solution. Thanks

Comment: Try:  `min_value + rand()*range`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Did you mean, if we consider TV as an example then, 1000+rand()*1100. Is that right?

Comment: The range for the tv is `100`, not `1100`.  `1100` is the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So are you basically looking for something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Product='TV' THEN (1000 + CONVERT(INT, (101)*RAND())) ELSE CASE WHEN Product='Refrigerator' THEN (800 + CONVERT(INT, (201)*RAND())) ELSE 0 END END FROM ProductTable
```

The idea is pretty simple when it comes to random number between @min & @max. See below:

```
SELECT @min + CONVERT(INT, (@Max-@min+1)*RAND())
```